# What does the blame command do in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

Can someone explain to me the purpose of the blame command in version control systems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It tells you who wrote/changed a particular line of code. 
Typically it allows you to ask them why they did something (or tell them to fix it).